# Laravel - Storing Emails in Database

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to find an option where I can store the body of an email message, the addresses it was sent to and the subject and store it in the database where it can be related back to various models. Is there such a way I can handle this?

I'm not sure where to start. I know there is a callback on the message sent, but if this can be related back to man different models with many different IDs, how can I save the relationship between that particular model a message was sent about in the database?

Comment: What models do you have in mind?

Comment: https://github.com/jsefton/laravel-mail-audit

Answer (score 0):

you might need to check polymorphic relations in laravel https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

basically what it does that it would allow you to have relations between you email model and multiple models

Comment: But how would I connect the message ID from a sent email to an email model?

Comment: basically how poly morphic works  is that it adds two columns to the emails table in your case:
   emailable_id - integer (this would be the id of the model customer->id)
    commentable_type - string (this would be the\ namespace of the model "App\Models\Customer")